# How can I display two or multiple errors in same showError field

Tags: android, retrofit2

So I need to make a call to the api that gives as a response multiple string Lists of error messages. I want to show all the errors in one list  in an editText using showError, but it shows only one. How can I show all of them at once with new line between them?

```
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < errors.size(); i++) {
            errorEditText.setError(errors.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concat the errors in a single string and then show them as error.

```
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    String errorsString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < errors.size(); i++) {
        errorsString = errorsString + errors.get(i).toString() + "\\n";
    }
    errorField.setError(errorsString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello @anMC try this one it will help you.

Combine all error from list in to one string with "\n" and apply it on seterror.

```
String multilineError = "Multiline Error \n Next Line \n Third line \n Fourth line";

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtName.getText().toString())) {
                    edtName.setError(multilineError);
                } 
            }
        });
```

[image: you can see display look like this]